# IPhone UI Testing - How to access delete key on keyboard

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode-ui-testing

I'm currently testing a textfield. I can select all the text, but then the keyboard pops up and I want to hit the delete key on the keyboard to delete all the text. How can I do this?

**What I currently have:**

```
[_app.menuItems[@"Select All"] tap];
```

**What I want:**

```
[_app.menuItems[@"Select All"] tap];
[_app.keyboard[@"delete"] tap]; // How do I do this?
```

Answer (score 3):

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let textField = app.textFields["myTextField"]
textField.tap()
textField.typeText(XCUIKeyboardKey.delete.rawValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send a delete key press using [`XCUIKeyboardKey.delete`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuikeyboardkey/1500827-delete).

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let textField = app.textFields["myTextField"]
textField.tap()
textField.typeKey(XCUIKeyboardKey.delete, modifierFlags: [])
```

Comment: There is no method call `typeKey` for `textfield`

Comment: @Oletha The confusion is due to the method you mentioned being a macOS only method while the question is asking about iOS. Apple's documentation mentions the typeKey:modifierFlags: method is macOS only on this page https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement?language=objc & you can see the #if TARGET_OS_OSX in XCUIElement.h's header near the method to support this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (swift) :
`yourTextField.typeText(XCUIKeyboardKeyDelete)`

in Obj-c:
`const XCUIKeyboardKey XCUIKeyboardKeyDelete;`

Take a look here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuikeyboardkeydelete?language=objc